# Close all running app or open start in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

In my phone the hardware buttons are not working so I want to make a app in which can bring up the start screen or close all apps so that the start screen appears.

Can we do this in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, neither closing apps nor going to the start screen are possible with the API available.

Answer (score 0):

Application.Current.Terminate() this is the code line that can help you out by closing the apps programmatically but is only allowed in very limited circumstances. Otherwise your app won't pass certification. 
See the documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/libr...v=vs.105).aspx